# Finding Invisible Recaptcha Callback Function of an external site

Tags: javascript, jquery, imacros, puppeteer, invisible-recaptcha

How can I manually find the callback function of invisible recaptcha?
The following is the website:- https://www.redbubble.com/auth/login

The following gives a string and not a function

```
___grecaptcha_cfg.clients[0].aa.l.callback
```

Plus, there doesn't seem to be any callback function in `<div class="g-recaptcha">`

I have tried the following [How to manually call (find) the ReCaptcha Callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974605/how-to-manually-call-find-the-recaptcha-callback-function)  by using `document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();` but, it doesn't seem to log me into the website.

Basically, what I want to do is, after putting up my login, password, and grecaptcha response (using some javascript automation script), I want to call the callback function so that it logs me into the website, but, when I click the login button, it pops up the invisible recaptcha, as a result, I am unable to login.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.